# Problema al guardar imagen de gráfica con pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo un script principal y una librería con una función.
La idea es que a partir de unos datos, genera una representación gráfica y guarda una imagen de la gráfica en .png
Todo funciona bien, excepto que la imagen .png que genera es una imagen en blanco.
Además,después de mostrar el gráfico, la consola me dice:

> matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xc8f37b8

Script principal:

```
import f02_graphs as gr

y = [1, 7, 3, 4]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

d = "Z:\Trabajos\Python 3\proyectos\p00_banco_de_pruebas"

gr.one_line(x, y, save=d, title='Kosovo')
```

Función de la librería:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def one_line(x, y, show=True, save=False, title="Title", xlab="Abscissa",
             ylab="Ordinate"):
    # Representa con una linea la lista de datos pasada como parametro.
    #
    # x: almacena los datos de la coordenada x.
    # show: determina si se muestra la grafica por pantalla.
    # save: almacena el directorio para guardar la grafica como una
    #       imagen. Si su valor es None, no se guarda la imagen.
    # title: titulo de la grafica.
    # xlab: etiqueta del eje x.
    # ylab: etiqueta del eje y.
    #
    # Creamos la grafica.
    plt.figure()
    # Dibujamos la representacion de los datos.
    plt.plot(x, y)
    # Añadimos el titulo.
    plt.title(title)
    # Añadimos las etiquetas a los ejes.
    plt.xlabel(xlab)
    plt.ylabel(ylab)
    # Añadimos una rejilla.
    plt.grid(True)
    # Ajustamos los ejes a la zona con datos.
    plt.axis('tight')
    #
    # Mostramos la imagen de la grafica por pantalla.
    if show:
        plt.show()
    #
    # Guardamos la imagen en un directorio introducido por el usuario.
    if save:
        plt.savefig('dragon.png')
```

Sin embargo, si en lugar de llamar a la función, lo hago todo en el script principal, se guarda sin problemas. Pero quiero hacerlo llamando a una función dentro de una libreria.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

PD: Trabajo con Spyder 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib considera figuras y ejes "actuales" a todo aquello que no ha sido mostrado mediante `show`. Cuando se llama a `plt.show()` se resetea todo lo que hubiera pendiente de mostrar creándose una nueva figura en blanco. No se si te habrás dado cuenta que si no muestras la figura si que se guarda correctamente. Podemos encontrar un aviso al respecto en la [documentación oficial](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show):

> **Note**
>
> Because closing a figure window invokes the destruction of its plotting elements, you should call savefig() before calling show if you wish to save the figure as well as view it.

lo que podríamos traducir algo así:

> **Nota**
>
> Como cerrar la ventana que muestra una figura invoca la destrucción de sus elementos gráficos, debes llamar a `savefig()` antes de llamar a `show()` si quieres guardar la figura además de verla.

Para resolver el problema puedes:

- Llamar primero a `plt.savefig` y luego a `plt.show` invirtiendo el orden de los condicionales.
- O bien usar una variable para almacenar la referencia a la instancia `matplotlib.figure.Figure` que quieres guardar:

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


  def one_line(x, y, show=True, save=False,
               title="Title", xlab="Abscissa", ylab="Ordinate"):

      figure = plt.figure()
      plt.plot(x, y)
      plt.title(title)
      plt.xlabel(xlab)
      plt.ylabel(ylab)
      plt.grid(True)
      plt.axis('tight')

      if show:
          figure.show()
      if save:
          figure.savefig('dragon.png')
  ```

Comment: He probado las dos formas que comentas y funciona correctamente. Sin embargo no entiendo por qué si lo pongo todo en el script principal funciona sin problemas y si lo pongo en forma de script principal + función, me da ese problema.

Comment: @Zhisi me extraña mucho lo que comentas. Yo al menos no puedo reproducir eso, ni usando un script ni en modo interactivo. Cualquier llamada a `show` destruye lo anterior como se espera. ¿Estás seguro de poder guardar adecuadamente la figura **después** de llamar a `show`?. He añadido una nota sobre esto que hay en la documentación algo escondida a la respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo he probado de nuevo y sigue sucediendo lo mismo. Si lo pongo todo en un único script, no importa el orden en que ponga `show()` y `savefig()`. He probado a reiniciar Spyder y Anaconda y sigue sucediendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente invierte el orden de los `if`. Y agrega el path de donde guardaras la imagen.
Por ejemplo:

En lugar de

```
if show:
  figure.show()
if save:
  figure.savefig('dragon.png')
```

Escribe:

```
if save:
  figure.savefig(d + '\dragon.png')
if show:
  figure.show()
```